# Get rid of crease in mesh

Tags: modeling

[image]

What would be the best way to get rid of / smooth a crease in sculpted mesh from joining to objects?

Comment: You could try the smooth tool in sculpt mode.

Comment: That was the first thing I tried. I even tried building it up and then smoothing it.

Comment: I was able to delete the second mesh. I kept highlighting everything with xray mode turned on, and then turning it off and un-highlighting anything I wanted to keep, before deleting the unwanted mesh inside.